# Three address code (example)

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

How can I describe suitable codes to implement:

```
Sum :=0;
for i from 1 to n do sum+= i endfor;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that there's no such thing as a "specification" for three-address code. It's typically used to refer to a family of intermediate representations with some common properties - most notably, the lack of complex expressions like `((x + 5) * z - y)`.

With that out of the way, here's an example of how it might look in a form of three-address code *that I just made up*.

```
  ; ... preceding code ...
  sum := 0
  i   := 1
  goto loop_header

loop_header:
  if i > n then loop_end else loop_body

loop_body:
  sum := sum + i
  i   := i + 1
  goto loop_header

loop_end:
  ; ... rest of function ...
```

The take-away is:

- In three-address code, complex expressions must be reduced to a series of simple expressions, introducing temporary variables to hold intermediate results as needed. For instance, we might translate the expression `x = ((x + 5) * z - y)` into:

  ```
   t0 := x + 5
   t1 := t0 * z
   x  := t1 - y
  ```

  Note that your example only contained simple expressions.
- Loops are replaced with simple jumps between labels. This brings the IR closer to the machine code it will eventually be translated to.

The format of the code reflects some of my personal preferences for a low-level IR:

1. There are no implicit fall-throughs; all [basic blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block) begin with a label and end in a `goto` or `if` (or a `return`, not shown).
2. At branching points, the `if` instruction contains both the true and the false target, eliminating the need for a following `goto`. It's also nicer on the instruction selector.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, now is the time to ask follow-up questions. :-)